# Webpack Laravel расположение и именование chunk при ленивой загрузке

Tags: laravel, webpack

Имеется ленивая подгрузка компонентов Vue. При компиляции Webpack именует чанки от 0 и кладет их в корень паблика. Один из способов именования и расположения чанков - "волшебные" комментарии `/* WebpackChunkName: "path/ChunkName" */`. Но это как-то не совсем по феншую.
Существует ли способ указать в конфигурации путь для чанков и именования (по имени компонента)? Как это делается в Laravel?